# Why is variance a fixed constant when modelling Linear Regression through MLE?

Tags: regression, variance, maximum-likelihood, heteroscedasticity

I was following a derivation of Linear Regression through MLE.

Here we model

[image]

Then we proceed to derive the negative log-likelihood through a series of steps as shown.

[image]

[image]

Finally we maximize the above to reach the same objective as the least square method.

What I am not sure of is, How can we treat the sigma as constant here when differentiating, isn't this sigma set by us when we are modeling y, and if this sigma is set by us, how do we choose this value of sigma?.

Down the line, we can calculate the Variance of theta/(w) which depends on  sigma.

[image]

How do we calculate the variance of w, if we don't know sigma?

I know we model our error of each data point as normally distributed Gaussian with variance sigma, aren't we choosing a definite value of sigma here when modelling?.

Apologies if what I say Is unclear, it would be helpful if someone can help me understand what role is sigma playing here?

**Clarification: The W_ml in the above is interchangeable with theta, which are all the parameters of the line.**

Comment: What is W? It doesn't appear in your MLE equations.

Comment: W = theta , the parameters of the line

Comment: There are some errors in your formulas, the first line with the loglikelihood $\ell$ the factor $1/\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}$ should be inside the product sign, not outside. Also, we have $\LaTeX$ on this site, please add formulas with $\LaTeX$ notation, not images. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference